# SVN commit and checkout

Tags: svn

I commit my application to SVN (in which repository is stored in my external harddisk) in one PC (it commits "successfully" to be Revision 9).
But somehow, when I checkout the same repository at other PC, it return "successfully" the older revision (Revision 7).

It happens few time.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of the log output?

Answer (score 3):

3. Make sure on the 'other PC' that you're checking out the latest revision for the branch
4. Make sure you're checking out from the same branch/trunk as you're committing to

Answer (score 2):

1. Look at your SVN log on both machines to verify the latest COMMIT.
2. Make sure you added all the files to the SVN Repository with ADD.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if the commit you just made on a given PC has been effective is to take the url of the given folder and paste it into a brwoser -- useful for a machine-independent check of a repo structure.

Also agree with KindJackal -- check to see if you are committing in some other branch (or tage even) and looking for it elsewhere.

svn log --limit=10 helps as well to see if the last 10 transactions include the commits you think you made.

Answer (score 0):

**svn update** the server ..it's not auto updating.